# Where do I change rule set of PMD on Eclipse?

Tags: pmd

I'm a newbie who use PMD on Eclipse first time. I'd like to change the rule sets of PMD on my Eclipse. Where do I customize my rule sets?

I've tried to find where to change my rule sets, but I couldn't see it.

I expected that there is Settings for PMD on the list that appear when clicking right button on the mouse on the project on Package Explorer, but I couldn't see any settings for PMD.

Answer (score 0):

You can find rule configuration in.
Window - Preferences - PMD - Rule Configurations.
Or Project properties for configuring project specific rule set.